# cannot install elementary OS by usb or hdd

Tags: usb-drive, macintosh, hdd

gggrr
please help!!

OK my situation:
I'm struggling with my 32bit MacBook with a defect dvd drive.

Managed to make an bootable USB stick, but the macbook won't recognize this stick, when booting up and pressing the option key.
I made an separate partition on the hdd but did't manage to make this bootable with a version of elementaryOS. I tried to copy ElementaryOS on the partition by the restore function of Disk Utility (OSX).
An error makes this impossible.

Does anyone knows a nifty trick to:
Make my old macbook recognize the bootable USB?
or
Copy elementaryOS on the hdd and boot from this partition?

I ran out of options and I hope on somebody out there with more tricks on his sleeves than me.
Regards, Jake

---

Thanks Rocco & Alexandr for your respond.
In addition to my post; I found a 32 bit version of ElementaryOS (elementaryos-0.3.2) I think it's called Freya.
I created a bootable USB-stick with Etcher on a other computer.
This stick won't appear in the bootable disk menu, booting up, pressing the option key. I cleared the PRAM to be sure the computer has no preferred disks.

How can I let my computer recognize the USB?

Grrr I going slightly mad!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try creating your bootable media with the app Etcher (https://etcher.io/). It has been the only app I have used where the bootable media is recognized in all the hardware I have used it with. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

just remember that elementary 0.4 Loki doesn't support 32 bit processors